# Rails - getting object's fields inside view when calling model's method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model, field

Im new to ruby and rails, however I cant figure out why this doesnt work.

I am doing a simple Blog with posts and its comments, everything works fine but I tried to do my own method inside Post model to get the latest comment inside that post.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title

  has_many :comments

    def latestComment(id)
        post = Post.find(id)
        comment = post.comments.last
    end
  end
```

and the index.html.erb

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<h2>Posts</h2>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>

    <h3><%= link_to post.title, post %></h3>
    <p><%= post.content %></p>

    <%= latestComment = post.latestComment(post) %>

<% end %>

<h3>Add new post</h3>
<%= link_to "Add new post", new_post_path %>
```

This works, it returns some hexa values, so the object exists, however then I now want to get fields from that object like this

```
<p><%= latestComment.author %></p>
<p><%= latestComment.content %></p>
```

It fails and the error is

```
undefined method `author' for nil:NilClass
```

which is weird and I dont get it why cant I access comments fields..

**///comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :author, :content, :post_id

    belongs_to :post
end
```

Comment: Try this instead <p><%= post.latestComment.author %> </p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looping over multiple posts, it's possible that one of them doesn't have any comments, which makes `post.comments.last` return nil. You can work around this by checking it before trying to render the comment:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def has_comments?
    comments.count > 0
  end

  def last_comment
    comments.last
  end
end
```

Then, on the view:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

  <h3><%= link_to post.title, post %></h3>
  <p><%= post.content %></p>

  <% if post.has_comments? %>
    <p><%= post.last_comment.author %></p>
    <p><%= post.last_comment.content %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yea youre right, comming from java, this is kinda confusing that it wouldnt throw somekind of nullpointer exception so i could figure it out right away but yea, suppose ill have to get used to it :D thanks !